# String Formatting + Blackberry + java

Tags: java, blackberry

I am facing a bit problem with formatting of string. In my application I need to send an email to a web service.The format of the email need to be like this

```
Name           Class            Section              Position    
Sam            5                A                    1    
Joseph         7                C                    4
```

For this I have used /n and /t for line breaks ans spacing. But the real problem is with the 'Name' item. The length of 'name' item varies. Currently my approach is that I am taking a reference string sufficiently long and padding blank spaces in each name string until its length is equal to the base String.

The problem that I am facing is that this approach doesn't work fine when I append blank spaces but instead of blank spaces if I append any other character say 'x' then the resulting string is properly formatted.

Function for appending blank spaces :

```
  private String getModifiedName(String name){
         String testString  = "This is a very big string";

         while(getFont().getAdvance(testString) > getFont().getAdvance(name)){
             name = name + " ";

         }



         return name;

     }
```

Comment: *Doesn't work fine* - do you mean, the webservice rejects the content of you email if you pad the name strings with bank spaces?

Comment: @Andreas_D : No, I mean that the format of the email is not correct. Correct format should that all names must be in one column, all class must be one columns. But here all these contents do not appear in distinct columns.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you mean that the layout is broken when you view the email? If the email supports HTML, then suggest you use table for alignment

Comment: @Manny : yes the layout is broken.. How should I use table in blackberry??

Comment: since blackberry os 4.5, html emails are supported. Not sure about your requirements though if you can include html email, double check your user requirements. Also, I'm not sure if your web service, automatically escapes html characters.  If html is supported, try formatting it with the normal HTML table e.g. <table><tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td></tr><tr><td>Val 1</td><td>Val 2</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`String.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) if it is there in the version of jdk you are using with blackberry

```
package org.life.java.so.questions;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class StringFormatDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Jigar";
        String header = String.format("Name \t Class \t Section \t Positoin");
        String dataRow1 = String.format("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s",name,"A","IT","JavaDev");
        System.out.println(header);
        System.out.println(dataRow1);
    }
}
```

- [IdeOne Demo](http://ideone.com/AhsD8)

**Update:**

As the above method is not there with your java env you can go for

[`javax.microedition.global.Formatter.formatMessage(...)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/global/Formatter.html)

Comment: life.java : I thought of this but my jdk doesn't have any method as String.format()

Comment: life.java :Hi can you please tell how to use this method??

Comment: please refer to its doc its almost same as above,

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you try to create an email body that *looks* well aligned in a viewer. And I guess, you're using a proportional font (like times or helvetica/arial).

Webservices usually don't care if the table *looks* aligned but care if the message *is* aligned. Make sure, that the number of chars is each column is the same, even if the result looks ugly on the screen. So really shouldn't use the `getFont().getAdvance()` method to make Strings (almost) equal size but use `String#size()` instead for padding.