# Striping a String of html tags in Blackberry Java

Tags: java, blackberry

I am parsing series of posts on a blog through an RSS feed, Fortunately the text() has series of html tags in it, i tried using replace() method but i get the following error:`The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String) Here is my code: String stripString = mDesCollect.replace("{\\<.*?\\>}", ""` in blackberry development. Please need way to strip this text of the tags?
Here is an example of the text:

```
<!-- [DocumentBodyStart:4accc09d-2c60-4371-956f-1293c4a9746a] --><div class="jive-rendered-content"><p>Hello everyone. Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who hath blessed us with all spiritual blessings in heavenly places in Christ (Ephesians 1:3). </p><p>We're in the second week of this special month of preparation. We'll pray at 12noon, 5pm and 10pm (GMT+1) for 15min, speaking in tongues fervidly and declaring words of faith regarding any situation of concern. God bless you.</p></div><!-- [DocumentBodyEnd:4accc09d-2c60-4371-956f-1293c4a9746a] -->
```

thank very much, I appreciate any help!

Comment: What does "refused to work" mean?

Comment: i meant replace was highlighted in red.

Comment: The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String) Here is my code: String stripString = mDesCollect.replace("{\\<.*?\\>}", "");

Comment: Consider updating your question to include the information in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Since using regex is a bad form (See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)), look at http://jsoup.org

Comment: Hello maksimov, Please I have some issues with preverifying this jsoup library (jsoup 1.6.3), I would like to have any suggested solution to the issue.

Comment: ISSUE: Error preverifying class org.jsoup.Connection$Base
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Comment: @donaldepig, this must be BB-specific. I'm afraid, I'm not really familiar with this. Try to google for similar issues with preverifying.

Comment: I have tried several searches, I found this : [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-jsoup-jar-in-blackberry/td-p/1470975#M186472) but I have tried the option (copying the sources files into my project) but it has lots of error.

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting? jsoup is supposed to run on Java 1.5+. If you're getting compile errors with your BB SDK, it would probably mean that the SDK is much more limited than the Java 1.5+ - API-wise.

Comment: The errors I get a mostly with String.format(); What I do is, I copy source files from jsoup into my project then along with the Blackberry   jre 5.0.39, I reference Java 1.5. Thats when I get the above errors.

Comment: If it's just the `String#format()` then I suppose you could try and patch it. See here for suggested replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612674/string-formatting-blackberry-java